# Downloading Ubuntu desktop 32-bit version

Tags: downloads

Como faço para baixar o ubuntu desktop 32 bits?
Não estou conseguindo, se puderem mandar o link de download ou explicar como baixar agradeço!

Translation

> How do I download the ubuntu 32-bit desktop? I can not, if you can send the download link or explain how to download thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest long term supported version of Ubuntu here:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads